# Ionic Header (v1) Custom HTML in header

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app

I would like to add some custom html (3 little weather icons) to the ion-nav-bar element in place of the right-side buttons. When I try to add the html it doesn't appear in the view though I can see the html in the inspector. I can't determine what is hiding it from view. If I stick a button element in their place that shows fine. If I don't put the custom html inside a ion-nav-button directive, the html itself disappears in the view

```
<ion-view>
    <ion-nav-bar class="tsw-dark">
        <ion-nav-buttons side='left'>
            <!-- this button shows fine -->
            <button menu-toggle="left" class="button button-clear button-icon icon ion-navicon home-icon"></button>
        </ion-nav-buttons>
        <ion-nav-buttons side='right'>
            <!-- the html inside this block does not render in the view though I can find it with the inspector -->
            <div class='t-h-wi'><i class='icon ion-ios-sunny-outline'></i></div>
            <div class='t-h-wi'><i class='icon ion-ios-sunny-outline'></i></div>
            <div class='t-h-wi'><i class='icon ion-ios-sunny-outline'></i></div>
        </ion-nav-buttons>
    </ion-nav-bar>   
<ion-content>
.....
```

Comment: Here is the pen where you can see those icons in the nav bar. 

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/evJvYz?editors=1010#0

I dont see any issue with your code. (Once check the positions of the element via inspector or changing position.)

Comment: Thanks! The plunker is different. In my code, the view containing the header is a separate file from index.html. Not sure if that makes a difference. Also it lives inside an <ion-view> directive. Again, not sure if that is important. I have updated the code in the question.

Comment: Argh! They're there. They are the same color as the background. Doh!!

Answer (score 0):

I feel pretty silly but sometimes the answer is as simple as 'the elements in question were the same color as the background', as it was this time.